# stripping one column to create a new column through query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a large pandas data frame where one of the columns is wrapped in double quotes and some of the rows have multiple values, so they are comma separated. I want to extract these values from the names column, by stripping the quotes and then iterate through each name (we don't have to skip the blank ones since the query result will just be blank) and get a query result that will be placed in a new column, also comma separated. The other thing is that I don't want any duplicates in my query results listed. I don't need help with how to get the query results, more so the other parts in between like the stripping of quotes and then making sure the results are placed in the correct places with no duplicates.

**(simplified) original pandas dataset**

```
 ID1     ID2       names         
 01      01         "John"         
 01      02         "Kate, Ashten"       
 01      03        
 01      04         "Emily, Cathy, Joy"
```

**desired dataset**

```
 ID1     ID2       names                  query_result_fav_color         
 01      01         "John"                    "pink"    
 01      02         "Kate, Ashten"            "blue"
 01      03
 01      04         "Emily, Cathy, Joy"       "red, green, blue"
```

**what I've tried**

```
values=original_df['names'] # series 
values=values.to_frame()
values = values.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('"',''))


#do the query (get a 'results' list)

results= ["pink", "blue", "blue", "NA", "red", "green", "blue"]

#put the results from the query in a new column that corresponds to the correct row (need help with this)
 ID1     ID2       names                  query_result_fav_color         
 01      01         "John"                    "pink"    
 01      02         "Kate, Ashten"            "blue", "blue"
 01      03                                   "NA"
 01      04         "Emily, Cathy, Joy"       "red", "green", "blue"

# remove duplicates in same row, and make sure only 1 set of quotes around the results (need help with this)
```

**EDIT**

```
#this works in the sample, but when I try it on my actual data set, I'm having some issues:

df = df.assign(names = df["names"].str.split(",")).explode(column="names").assign(query_result_fav_color=results).groupby(["ID1", "ID2"])["names", "query_result_fav_color"].agg(list)

df.assign(
    names=df["names"].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x) if x else ""),
    query_result_fav_color=df["query_result_fav_color"].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x))
).reset_index()

#this is what my dataset looks like when I try the solution (please focus on rows 3-5). It ends up duplicating whenever there is more than 1 entry and then will continue listing the other color in the next row. 
-------------------------------------------------
    ID1 ID2 names               query_result_fav_color
0   01  01  John                pink
1   01  02  Kate, Ashton        blue, blue
2   01  03                      NA
3   01  04  Emily, Cathy, Joy   red, red, red
4   01  05  Jason               green
5   01  06                      blue  

-------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What kind of database are you using (mysql, sqlite, etc)? This can be done without using any scripting language. Just use a query that will do this for you.

Comment: so basically you want to repeat `query_result_fav_color` according to the number of names you have in `names` right?

Comment: Yes (if I understand you correctly- I would be doing to be doing the query 7 times-including the blank name). I think it would be easier to include the blank name so that it is easier to map perhaps?

Comment: if that is so why `(simplified) original pandas dataset` has only value `"Kate" ` for the second row?

Comment: Oops, that was a typo (should be two names). Thank you!

Comment: is it guranteed that size of query_result_fav_color   would always be n*names  ?

Comment: Yes, it is since I made it so that if there is no query result to return "NA".

Comment: okay wait a jiffy I am providing an answer

Comment: I am stuck at the part where I've removed the quotes from 'values' and I need to access each name within it, but it's kind of hard because it is in a pandas df. After being able to access each name, I can do a for loop query for each name. I also need help with what I do after I get the 'results'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you already replaced '"' with '' (not necessary for the code to run) in your frame so that you have the following data frame and list:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID1": ["01"] * 4, "ID2": ["01", "02", "03", "04"], "names": ["John", "Kate, Ashton", "", "Emily, Cathy, Joy"]})
results= ["pink", "blue", "blue", "NA", "red", "green", "blue"]
```

You can convert the values from 'names' to lists and explode your data frame. Then you just have to assign your list to the exploded frame (which matches the length of the list now) and re-group it back by your 'ID' columns. For this, you do not really need another package besides of `pandas`. Just do something like this:

```
df = df.assign(names = df["names"].str.split(",")).explode(column="names").assign(query_result_fav_color=results).groupby(["ID1", "ID2"])["names", "query_result_fav_color"].agg(list)

df.assign(
    names=df["names"].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x) if x else ""),
    query_result_fav_color=df["query_result_fav_color"].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x))
).reset_index()

-------------------------------------------------
    ID1 ID2 names               query_result_fav_color
0   01  01  John                pink
1   01  02  Kate, Ashton        blue, blue
2   01  03                      NA
3   01  04  Emily, Cathy, Joy   red, green, blue
-------------------------------------------------
```

If you want to have an one-liner that does this, here you go:

```py
(
    df.assign(query_result_fav_color=df.assign(names = df["names"].str.split(","))
           .explode(column="names").drop(columns=["names"])
           .assign(query_result_fav_color=results)
           .groupby(["ID1", "ID2"])["query_result_fav_color"]
           .agg(list).apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x) if x else "").values)
)
```

Comment: This almost works but I'm running into some issues (please see edit to my post).

Comment: @youtube, can you provide your list named `results` for the new data frame? According to the ouput, it should equal `["pink", "blue", "blue", "NA", "red", "red", "red", "green", "blue"]`